# Copying Script with innerHTML and quotes

Tags: javascript, html

At the bottom of my HTML page I have declared a div with the text of a JavaScript function.

```
<div style="display:none" id="newwinner">
function newwin()
{ nwin = window.open("","_blank", "scrollbars,menubar,toolbar, status,resizable,location");
  content = document.body.innerHTML;
  if(nwin != null)
  { nwin.document.write("<html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' /></head><body>"+content+"</body></html>");
    nwin.document.close();
  }
}
</div>
```

Now I want to insert that somewhere else. This gets the JavaScript code:

```
  nw = document.getElementById("newwinner");
  var g = document.createElement("script");
  g.text = nw.innerHTML;
  var tab = document.getElementById("Maintable");
  tab.insertBefore(g, tab.childNodes[0]);
```

I always get the same error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

[image: This is how it look in Chrome]

The problem is the second level of quotes, like `'Content-Type'`. It looks like the single quotes are converted to double quotes here. That is what I see both in the Chrome console and when I do an `alert()`.

I tried many variations, escaping with backslashes, using escaped double quotes, using `&quot;`, but none of them solved the problem. What can I do to solve this?

Note that this is specific for a script node. When I use a DIV instead it works.

Comment: What do you want to achive with your code ?

Comment: What do you mean "When I use a DIV instead it works." It doesn't execute the code, right? So how does it "work"? Also, why not just put the code in a `script` element in the first place?

Comment: You do know that a `div` tag will just display the text of the code while the `script` tag will execute it?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Indeed, a DIV doesn't execute the code. But this error happens when I insert the script into the page - and that doesn't execute the code either as it is only a function declaration.

Comment: Yes, it occurs because it is a syntax error, which happen when the JavaScript parser loads the `script` element. I suggest sticking with a `script` element and fixing the syntax error rather than trying to do the same while keeping it in a `div`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey  Where do you see a syntax error? When this code is part of the page it executes normally.

Comment: In `g.text = nw.innerHTML;`, what is 'nw'? It's not declared anywhere. Also, 'Maintable'. There seems to be stuff missing that we probably need to know about.

Comment: "Where do you see a syntax error?" In your question: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: more better if you include snippet in your question

Comment: @wazz I forgot one line in the code - the one that defines nw. That has been added now.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I added the picture of what you get when you click the error message.

Comment: So, I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mikemccaughan/487o5sb1/) with this code in a `script` element and there are no errors... So why are you trying to use a `div` element to hold it and then transfer it to a `script` element? Also, it would probably work if you used `nw.innerText` or `nw.textContent`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks, InnerText did the trick.

Comment: It has to be noted that a) it is a really bad idea to use `document.write` and b) as it stands, your `document.write` will create totally invalid html as the resulting page won't even have a `body`or a `head`, let alone a root element or DOCTYPE. The browser correcting this for you is absolutely no excuse for performing such actions. If what you need to do cannot be achieved in a non-dirty, secure way, that means yes, you should stop doing that altogether.